# flutter problem: Hoe to make active color change for listview?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

### I want that when i click any list then that list background color should be change.

I want that when i click any list then that list background color should be change.

I want that when i click any list then that list background color should be change.
I want that when i click any list then that list background color should be change.

this is my code

```
import 'package:bonana_flutter/Constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  List<ProfileModel> listModel = [
    ProfileModel("assets/setting_icon.png", "Profile Settings",
        "Edit user profile details.",true),
    ProfileModel("assets/add_member_icon.png", "Add Family Member",
        "Link multiple members using PAN.",true),
    ProfileModel(
        "assets/rne_icon.png", "Refer & Earn", "Invite your friends and earn.",false),
    ProfileModel(
        "assets/pns_icon.png", "Privacy & Security", "Change MPIN & Password",false),
    ProfileModel("assets/notification2_icon.png", "Notifications",
        "Toggle app notifications on & off.",false),
    ProfileModel("assets/hns_icon.png", "Help & Support", "",false),
    ProfileModel("assets/logout_icon.png", "Logout", "",false),
  ];
bool isSelected = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: Drawer(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: skyBlue,
          title: Text(
            "Profile",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: tSize16),
          ),
          actions: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                    child: IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset(
                          "assets/phone_icon.png",
                          height: 25,
                          width: 25,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {}))
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: skyBlue,
                height: 150,
                child: nameView(),
              ),
              listView(),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

extension WidgetExtension on _ProfilePageState {
  nameView() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 5, bottom: 20),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 110,
              width: 110,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage(
                        'assets/dummy2.png',
                      ),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              //child: Image.asset("lib/Assets/clinic.png")
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 6.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        // bellazTitle(
                        //     (updatedName == "null") || (updatedName == null)
                        //         ? widget.uName!
                        //         : updatedName.toString(),
                        //     22),
                        Container(
                          // color: Colors.red,

                          child: Text(
                            "Chetan Singh",
                            maxLines: 1,
                            // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: tSize16,
                                color: skyBlue,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "PAN: *0978",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: tSize11,
                      color: greyColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 25,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: skyBlue, shadowColor: Colors.transparent),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const Text('Switch Account'),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  listView() {
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: listModel.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, position) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              InkWell(onTap: (){
            setState(() {
              isSelected = listModel[position].active;
            });
            print(isSelected);
              },
                child: Container(color: isSelected ? Colors.red :Colors.white ,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10,bottom: 10,left: 20,right: 20),
                  child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(listModel[position].img,
                              height: 24, width: 24),
                          SizedBox(width: 20,),
                          Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                listModel[position].title,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: tSize14,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    color: blackColor),
                              ),  SizedBox(height: 5,),
                              position == 5 || position == 6
                                  ? Container()
                                  : Text(
                                      listModel[position].subTitle,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: tSize11,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          color: blackColor),
                                    ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [Container(
                  width: 80,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 4.0),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                          size: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),)],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // ListTile(
              //     contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 0),
              //     horizontalTitleGap: 0,
              //     dense: true,
              //     onTap: () {
              //       switch (position) {
              //         case 0:
              //
              //           // Navigator.push(
              //           //     context,
              //           //     MaterialPageRoute(
              //           //         builder: (context) => BooklingTab()));
              //           break;
              //         case 1:
              //         // Navigator.push(
              //         //     context,
              //         //     MaterialPageRoute(
              //         //         builder: (context) => RewardsTab()));
              //           break;
              //         case 2:
              //           // Navigator.push(
              //           //     context,
              //           //     MaterialPageRoute(
              //           //         builder: (context) => Favourate()));
              //           break;
              //       // case 3:
              //       //   Navigator.push(context,
              //       //       MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AllTransactions()));
              //       //   break;
              //         case 3:
              //           // Navigator.push(
              //           //     context,
              //           //     MaterialPageRoute(
              //           //         builder: (context) => TermsOfUse()));
              //           break;
              //
              //         case 4:
              //           // Navigator.push(
              //           //     context,
              //           //     MaterialPageRoute(
              //           //         builder: (context) => HelpSupport(
              //           //             uName: widget.uName.toString())));
              //           break;
              //         case 5:
              //         // Navigator.push(
              //         //     context,
              //         //     MaterialPageRoute(
              //         //         builder: (context) => HelpSupport(
              //         //             uName: widget.uName.toString())));
              //           break;
              //
              //         case 6:
              //         // Navigator.push(
              //         //     context,
              //         //     MaterialPageRoute(
              //         //         builder: (context) => HelpSupport(
              //         //             uName: widget.uName.toString())));
              //           break;
              //         default:
              //       }
              //     },
              //     leading: Column(   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              //       children: [
              //         Image.asset(listModel[position].img,
              //             height: 24, width: 24),
              //       ],
              //     ),
              //     title: Text(
              //       listModel[position].title,
              //       style: TextStyle(
              //           fontSize: tSize14,
              //           fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              //           color: blackColor),
              //     ),
              //     subtitle:position == 5 || position == 6 ? null : Text(
              //       listModel[position].subTitle,
              //       style: TextStyle(
              //           fontSize: tSize11,
              //           fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              //           color: blackColor),
              //     ),
              //     trailing: Container(
              //       width: 80,
              //       child: Row(
              //         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              //         children: [
              //           Padding(
              //             padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 4.0),
              //             child: Icon(
              //               Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
              //               size: 18,
              //             ),
              //           ),
              //         ],
              //       ),
              //     )),
              Divider()
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}

class ProfileModel {
  String title;
  String subTitle;
  String img;
bool active;
  ProfileModel(this.img, this.title, this.subTitle,this.active);
}
```

This is my code ui screen shot
[image]

I want like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The listview  will need to be created in the build of a State of a StatefulWidget, and the State must have a member variable bool pressAttention = false;(or whatever you want to name it).  you need to make state changes in a setState callback for the Widget to redraw. Below is an example if it where a button. Look at color, when button is pressed pressAttention toggles which toggles the color

```
new RaisedButton(
  child: new Text('Attention'),
  textColor: Colors.white,
  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
  ),
  color: pressAttention ? Colors.grey : Colors.blue,
  onPressed: () => setState(() => pressAttention = !pressAttention),
);
```